# Loading data from API in background

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I am currently trying to improve my UX. 
When a User switches to a new component, it takes about 0.5 to 1 second until their data is loaded and shown in the view. So for the first moments, the view is empty, some parts are missing or displayed wrong.

I understand that there is the angular resolve interface. However as far as I understand, it is just delaying the rendering of the view until the data is available.

I was wondering whether there is an option, where you can load the data in the background after the landing page of my app is rendered. This way the user can already use and view the app, and in the background without them noticing the data for the other pages/components is being loaded.

Or maybe there is even a better approach or maybe my understanding of the resolve interface is just wrong.

**Edit:** 
Providing an example, how my code currently works:
In the Service File:

```
getTiers () {
      return this.http.get(this.authService.getApiEndpoint(), this.authService.getRequestOptions())
      .map(
        (response: Response) => {
          const data = response.json();
          return data;
        }
      );
```

In my components file:
ngOnInit() {
    this.getTiers();

}

```
  getTiers () {
    this.tierService.getTiers()
      .subscribe(
        (tiers) =>
          this.tiers = tiers.data,
        (error) => console.log(error),
        () => this.initializingCompleted = true
      );
  }
```

In my template file:

```
    <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let tier of tiers">
        <ul class="table">
          <li class="title">
            {{ tier.title }}
          </li>
[...]
```

Comment: You could use a service to load the data you need in the background.

Comment: Use AJAX. When the data is loaded, update your angular component.

Comment: Improve it... from what? Give a [mcve] that demonstrates your current approach, otherwise it's tricky to suggest what might be better.

Comment: I am using a service to load the data, however the finale call using .subscribe takes place in my component. Or are you talking about something different? @Ploppy
How does AJAX work?

Comment: Improving from the current situation. As explained, I dont want the page to look broken while the data is being loaded and I dont want the use to wait before going to the next page/component @jonrsharpe

Comment: If you subscribe in your component, then you're not loading the data in the service. You should subscribe to the http.get() in your service and store the data in rxjs BehaviorSubject. And finally your component should subscribe to the BehaviorSubject objects. This way your data will be loaded in the service and persist when your components are unloaded.

Comment: What you have *will* load the data in the background after the component has loaded, that's *why* the view is initially empty. I think you're probably looking in the wrong place for performance improvements: how fast is your server responding?

Comment: I know it will load in the background AFTER the component has loaded, however I was looking into a solution which loads this data before the component is loaded but AFTER the app is initialized and the landing page rendered @jonrsharpe
I think the aproach of Ploppy is an improvement

Comment: It can be done *somehow*. It's hard to suggest anything specific without knowing the details. The question doesn't contain http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , as it was mentioned above. Consider providing a fiddle/plunk that can replicate your situation, so the answers could address the case directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a service that is available all over the app to load the data and store it in a rxjs BehaviorSubject.

```
public data$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

constructor(private http: Http){
  this.http.get(...).map(...).subscribe(res => this.data$.next(res))
}
```

Then from your component:

```
public data: any;

constructor(private myService: MyService){
  this.data = this.myService.data$.value;
  this.myService.data$.subscribe(res => this.data = res);
}
```

NB: If you need to reset the value of the behavior subject `data$.next(null)`

Comment: We've used this pattern too (I wrote about it on my blog: http://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html) but beware stale data being shown; we found users got confused when they switched and still saw the previous data for a second.

Comment: From what I understand it seems to be some static data. Otherwise it would not be possible to preload it.

Comment: Data is not static, however only the user i able to change the data, so whenever there are changes made, I reload the data. Than there should be no issue right? Thanks @Ploppy

Comment: Yeah you can even reset the value of the BehaviorSubject by doing `data$.next(null)` if you don't want the confusing thing explained by @jonrsharpe above. Please, accept the answer if it fits you.

Comment: Can't get the solution to work. Still having the delay before data is available. Is there a way to move this discussion to a private chat? @Ploppy

Comment: If you keep commenting it will ask for a private discussion. Which should be really soon.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to force one though.

Comment: Is your data really big? Rendering a lot of data can take some times on low-end devices.

Comment: Alright, right now when I load the component the value is null and I have to wait a little before the correct value are available

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147577/discussion-between-junior-dn-and-ploppy).

Answer (score -1):

Asynchronous loading of data is one of the benefits of using Angular. Because it is a single page application, upon loading the landing page, if you use async methods appropriately, will help your resolve this issue. Take a look at this article https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-ways-to-pass-async-data-to-angular-2-child-components

Good luck